# slide image using php

Tags: php, html, css

i am trying to slide image using only php.
    i have try following code to slide image from array.
    but its only shows only one fullsize image in new window.
    The code is:
    What should i write in header to see slideshow with next image.
     and
      $images[$i]="uploads/".$img;
    Is this correct to store image name with folder path "uplods" into $images array.

```
i have refer this site for code:
http://www.sitepoint.com/picture-showcase-php-html/







<?php
          $sql="SELECT * FROM gallary WHERE aid='$aid'";
          $res=mysql_query($sql);
          $count=mysql_num_rows($res);                  


                    for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++)
                      {
                            $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                            $img=stripslashes($row['image']);                 
                            $images[$i]="uploads/".$img;
                      }//end of for
                         //print_r($images);
                         $total=count($images); 
                        $secondsFixed=10; // seconds to keep list the same <br>  
                        $seedValue=(int)(time()/$secondsFixed); 
                        srand($seedValue); 

                        for ($i=0;$i<$total;++$i) // shuffle list 'randomly' <br>  
                        { 



                                $r=rand(0,$total-1); 
                                $temp =$images[$i]; 
                                $images[$i]=$images[$r]; 
                                $images[$r]=$temp; 
                        }

                        $index=(int)($_GET['i']); // image index passed in <br>  
                        $i=$index%$total; // make sure index always in bounds <br>  
                        $file=$images[$i]; 
                        header("Location:"); // and pass file reference back <br>  
                        ?>  
                     </div>

            </div><!--End of right Container -->
```

Comment: Hi @swapnil.  Shouldn't you be passing in a file reference like this "header("Location: $file");"?

Comment: Your question is confusing, PHP can't build or manage a client side slideshow for you, you would output all your images with PHP and then use Javascript to manipulate them into a slideshow. Forgive me if I've got the wrong end of the stick but this is what you're question lead me to believe.

Comment: @MillyMonster:if i pass $file it show image with Url/path/image not slide images

Comment: What???? php for client side?????, second one today...!!

Comment: what should i do to slideimages that i have store in $images array??      suggest me??

Comment: Use jQuery instead...don't use php for client side things

Comment: Yeah I'd go a different route too. There are loads of good tutorials such as http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-an-auto-scrolling-slideshow-that-works-with-and-without-javascript/?search_index=2 but nettuts+ in general is a good place to look.